# Using Custom SPItem Event Receiver in Leave Request Form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have a custom leave request form on SP 2016 On premise, There are three levels of approval. How do I manage the permissions on the list item through SharePoint object Model.

Please refer to this link as my leave request is similar to this: [LeaveRequest](https://jamilhaddadin.com/2011/12/03/implementing-workflow-using-infopath-2010-and-sharepoint-designer-2010/)